# Как в Eclipse избавиться от ложных ошибок таких как не найдено пространство имен std и тому подобное

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, ide

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как избавиться в eclipse C++ ide от ошибок которых по сути нет ? У меня он все подчеркивает красным почти всегда и не поймешь где ошибка а где нет... На скрине один тесовый проект который в ток же Eclipse компилится и исполняется нормально.

Быть может посоветуете ide с не менее хорошим функционалом но без подобных глюков ?

Какую среду Вы используете, какая наилучшая по Вашему мнению ?

Answer (score 1):

Надо отключить некоторые или все опции анализа текста

Windows/Preferences:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну подсказки то лишними не будут опечатки - обычное дело, однако хотелось бы что бы он нормально текст анлизировал а не так как сейчас...

Comment: я не смог ничего изменить, просто отключаю, нормальный анализ видел только в XCode и VS, в QtCreator недавно появилось, но тоже пока отключаю

Comment: VS - (Visual Studio or Visual Code ?) 
XCode гуглил он только под мак ? На Линукс есть ?

Comment: visual studio имел ввиду, в линуксе пользуюсь qtcreator-ом и eclipse, больше не пробовал. Visual Code наверное можно настроить, но это какая-то полу-IDE, я её для скриптов использую

Comment: Qt нормально анализирует все ? А то у меня eclipse спотыкается на ровном месте иногда даже во время компиляции где точно ошибок нет.